# Framework for manipulating digital signatures

Tags: elliptic-curves, tls, dsa, pki

for a research project, i am currently looking for a way to manipulate the digital signature of a HTTPS TLS message flow. More specifically, i am trying to create a working example for a malicious webserver in order to show a client-side exploit of CVE-2022-21449 ("Psychic Signatures") for a research paper.

In order to do this, i am planning to write a small HTTPS-capable TLS server which will sign the message with a digital ECDSA signature with the parameters r and s set to zero. In theory, this should cause the vulnerable java-based client to regard the malicious payload as a valid response as opposed to throwing an exception. Sadly, i have not been able to find a framework or tool for appending this invalid signature to the payload sent by a standard Java SSLServerSocket. The only option i see is modifying the Java security library directly in order to change how the signature is generated when using the "SHA256withECDSA" (for example) algorithm. I have found this repository showing a PoC for this exact case, but it is written in go. If possible, i would like to write my own server (out of curiosity). I don't care about the language i am writing it in.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.se The ethic is not cross-posting. Please delete one copy. see here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/403350

Comment: Done. I think this board might be the better place for it.

Comment: So you have found a PoC written in Go. You don't care a about the language you will use for your own code. So then why not simply look at the PoC you already know and learn from it how to do it. Since it obviously doable in Go you can just do it yourself in Go too.

Comment: You can create a provider for Java with an Signature service that supplies ECDSA. Then when the signing happens (possibly with a special key) you can simply return all zeros. Creating a provider is somewhat hard, but Java has always had a tutorial for doing so. Place the provider in front of all the other providers and your uncle may well be called Bob.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the way it was done in the Go PoC is that the Go Standard Library was copied to the Repo. They simple commented out some Code for verifying Certificates and the „r“ and „s“ Parameters of the ECDSA algorithm. I wanted to create a working example without having to edit Core Library files.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you, this actually helped a lot! I didn‘t know you could simply and your own provider at runtime. I tried inheriting from the ECDSASignature class, but sadly, it is package-private and thus I can‘t call it directly. Do you know if there is any other way, for example using Bouncycastle?

Comment: Why do you need to inherit from it if you're just going to return zeros? Otherwise just take the source code and alter that.